# Sqlite foreign key one field two tables

Tags: sqlite

I have table product:

```
codart
p1  
p2
```

variant table (store only product with a variant):

```
codart-codvar
p3 -    1
p3 -    2
p4 -    1
```

I have also a stock table like
so

```
codart-codvar-qty
p1    -      -100
p4    - 1    -100
```

table definition

```
CREATE TABLE Stock ( Codart text NOT NULL, Codvar text NOT NULL, Qty real NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT FK_Variants FOREIGN KEY(Codart,Codvar) REFERENCES Variants(Codart,Codvar) ON DELETE CASCADE, CONSTRAINT FK_Products FOREIGN KEY(Codart) REFERENCES Products(Codart) ON DELETE CASCADE, CONSTRAINT PK_Stock PRIMARY KEY(Codart,Codvar) )
```

If i insert product with variant like so

insert into stock (codart,codvar,rkaesiste)
values('prod1','1',10)

no error
but if it try

insert into stock (codart,codvar,rkaesiste)
values('prod1','',10)

get

SqliteException: SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.

I would fk point two tables but i do not know if possible
what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You will get that error because `codvar` is meant to be from values that are in the primary table, so the empty string value ('') may not work cos it doesn't exist in the primary table.

Comment: There s no way to refer both table for same field?

Comment: I would insert both...product with and without variant. Problem is variant table has only products that has variant

Comment: Should i desist?